# Sendmail temp file filling the filesystem causing server issues

Tags: centos, centos6, sendmail

For the last few days, sendmail has been generating an enormous temp file, which is deleted, but still linked by the application.

Here is the output of `lsof -a +l1 /`

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE      SIZE/OFF NLINK     NODE NAME
sendmail 10547 root    0r   REG  253,0 2058224971776     0 30670859 /tmp/fileeteaAd (deleted)
```

You can see the file is 2.05 TB (which is the size of the disk). How do I go about debugging this to see how this is happening, and is there a way to configure sendmail so that it can't do this? This server has been running for years without issue until recently.

Centos 6.2, I can't seem to figure out how to get the sendmail version.

Comment: `rpm -qf $(which sendmail)` should tell you the package.

Comment: Why is your system so many years out of date?